# GPS TCP communication

Tags: java, tcp, gps, jms, netty

My server receives GPS data from gps device at a port(5557) and using apache camel netty it forwards the data to a class:

```
  from("netty:tcp://0.0.0.0:5557?textline=true&sync=false&tcpNoDelay=true").bean(DataReceiverService.class,"decisionMaker")
```

Receiver class :

```
 def decisionMaker(Exchange exchange) {
        String gpsData = exchange.in.body.toString();
```

We receive the data as comma-separated values and we save it in DB.

Now, we also want to send data back to GPS device using tcp. As you can see the data gets forwarded from port 5557 to a class with no access to TCP port/socket.

How can I do 2-way communication and send some data back to GPS device ?

Comment: Create a TCP server application that wait for connections at port 5557. When new connection is accepted, the application should write to db and send the response through the client socket.